# Sveltekit Websocket HMR with Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, sveltekit

I have a docker-compose file that launch 3 services. A nginx instance that listen to localhost:80 and forward to my 2 other services : A `Website` and `Sveltekit App` Services

Both of them are working great with my initial Nginx config. `Website` is available at http://localhost:80 and `Sveltekit app` at http://app.localhost. But sveltekit Hot reload with websocket can't connect and I don't know why.

My services are not exposing any ports inside **docker-compose.yml**, they share the same network as Nginx.

```yaml
nginx:
    image: nginx:1.25.3-alpine3.18
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - nginx:/var/log/nginx
    networks:
      - public
    logging:
      driver: none

app:
    build:
      dockerfile: dockerfile.dev
      context: app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/home/node
      - /home/node/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    networks:
      - public

website:
    build:
      dockerfile: dockerfile.dev
      context: website
    volumes:
      - ./website:/home/node
      - /home/node/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    networks:
      - public
```

Inside my **vite.config.ts**. I expose the HMR port to 3003 with host 0.0.0.0 (docker need it). The plugin above just replace the client-side HMR host to be "app.localhost" (the url where the sveltekit app service is accessible).

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit(),
        {
            name: "client-host",
            transform(code, id) {
              if (
                id.endsWith("dist/client/client.mjs") ||
                id.endsWith("dist/client/env.mjs")
              ) {
                return code.replace(
                  "__HMR_HOSTNAME__",
                  "app.localhost"
                );
              }
      
              return code;
            },
        }
    ],
    server: {
        host: "0.0.0.0",
        port: 80,
        watch: {
            usePolling: true,
            interval: 500
        },
        hmr: {
            host: "0.0.0.0",
            port: 3003,
        }
    },
```

Both Ports are exposed during my **dockerfile** build.

```
# [...]
# Sveltekit HTTP port
EXPOSE 80
# Sveltekit HMR Websocket
EXPOSE 3003
# [...]
```

and my nginx.config routes the services together :

```
http {
   server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://website:80;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app.localhost;
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app:80;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 3003;
        server_name app.localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app:3003;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
```

The browser seek for the url `ws://app.localhost:3003/` but the connection still fail and I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: You have an additional Nginx stanza listening on port 3003, but that's not published out to the host using `ports:`.  Does adding a line for that port help?